# store post value in session variable

Tags: codeigniter, session

i post value through ajax in codeigniter controller function , and trying to store value in session like this

```
function abc{
$studio = $_POST['studio'];
$trnr_type = $_POST['trnrtyp'];
$this->session->set_userdata('studio',$studio),$this->session->set_userdata('trnr_type',$trnr_type)
}
```

and use this value

```
$st = $this->session->userdata('studio');
$tr = $this->session->userdata('trnr_type');
```

but not getting value in session variable.

Comment: I have added my answer I hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Load the session library in your controller by the following

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

then you have to post the data to the codeigniter controller
then at the controller you have to do the following

```
$sess_array = array(
                  'studio' => $this->input->post('studio'),
                  'trnr_type' => $this->input->post('trnrtyp'),
                   );
$this->session->set_userdata('studio',$sess_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//set user data
$this->session->set_userdata('username',$username);


//get user data
if($this->session->has_userdata('username'))
{
    $userid = $this->session->userdata('username');

}
```

Hope this is what u are looking for

Comment: Also check inside the autoload.php file for the following line
$autoload['drivers'] = array('session');
if the above line does not appear please add it to auto load the session

Answer (score 0):

Before call abc function load sesion library

```
function abc() {
   $session = array('studio'=>$_POST['studio'],'trnr_type'=>$_POST['trnrtyp']);
   $this->session->set_userdata($session);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. Load session library into your controller:**

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

**2. Get your data:**

```
$studio = $this->input->post('studio'); 
$trnrtyp = $this->input->post('trnrtyp');
```

**3. Set session data:**

```
$this->session->set_userdata('studio', $studio); 
$this->session->set_userdata('trnrtyp ', $trnrtyp );
```

**4. Get session data:**

```
$st = $this->session->userdata('studio');
$tr = $this->session->userdata('trnr_type');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what the user guide says to do

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#adding-session-data

```
public function abc() {

    $sessiondata = array(
        'studio' => $this->input->post('studio'),
        'trnrtyp' => $this->input->post('trnrtyp')
    );

    $this->session->set_userdata($sessiondata);
}
```

Make sure you have set your session save path on config.php don't leave it null